Data disappearing from HMI tabs. How can I stop this?
I have a machine which is working since 2019, without any problem, but yesterday the StationDataAccess and TypeDataAccess tabs on the HMI lost data.
We have tried to input data manually again and save but as soon as I change tab or push any other menu the data disappears.
Reeboting the HMI did not help.
Does anybody have any clue how can thsis problem solved?

Inserting data manually again and saving.
Rebooting the HMI.

